absolute difference giving minus percentages
I have a DataFrame to find the percentage of absolute difference between two sources in python. But when I use the below code, few of the columns are giving the -% (minus percentages)
I have checked the columns showing minus percentage datatypes are same in both the sources.
Can anyone help me to find out why?
    # Define the columns you want to process
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# Create the results DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame()

results_df['date'] = c_df['date']
results_df['id'] = c_df['id']

for col in columns:
    # calculating the absolute difference
    diff = np.abs(c_df[f'{col}_s1'] - c_df[f'{col}_s2'])

    # calculating mean for snowflake columns
    norm_diff = abs(c_df[f'{col}_s1'].mean())

    # Avoid division by zero
    if norm_diff == 0:
        percentage = np.zeros(len(diff))
    else:
        # calculating percentage difference b/w the columns in both datasets
        percentage = (diff / norm_diff) * 100

    # Round the percentage_difference and add % symbol
    results_df[col] = [f"{round(diff)}%" for diff in percentage]

display(results_df)

I have added abs for the norm_diff and its working fine.
And the results are something like this.



a
b
c
d




0%
5%
10%
-5%


10%
100%
-50%
200%




Can't be sure without seeing your data, but it could be the way you're calculating norm_diff. When you run norm_diff = c_df[f'{col}_s1'].mean(), you'll end up with negative values if the average for the column is negative.  That would give you a negative value when you calculate percentage later.
Try logging the value of norm_diff and percentage after each loop; if this is what's happening, percentage will be negative exactly when norm_diff is.
Depending on what you're looking for, you might be able to fix this just by taking the absolute value when you calculate norm_diff:
- norm_diff = c_df[f'{col}_s1'].mean()
+ norm_diff = abs(c_df[f'{col}_s1'].mean())


I have edited the code in the question by adding abs to norm_diff and its working fine now.
